# Why has there been a recent surge in close votes to review?

Tags: discussion

[image]

On a normal day, I'll see two to four suggested closures in the review queue - but over the past week or so, it seems to have been **much** higher - seven? when I checked yesterday, and eleven today.

Is there a provable reason why this is?
Are there usage statistics that show a surge of new users or just more questions in general?
Is this just a coincidence?

Am I the only one noticing and this isn't abnormal at all?

Comment: I noticed it too. Perhaps it's a statistical fluctuation. It might be more new users or questions generally. Some questions were older questions too. Possibly some people are feeling a rush of blood and want to close more questions. It might be temporary.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of the marked questions that I would personally consider on topic/fine.  Please be diligent in actually evaluating the queue rather than just vtc'ing stuff.

Comment: The overall number of questions and answers is within normal levels. Possibly it's just a coincidence, possibly we've had an influx of new users, or maybe someone is being a bit over-zealous on the flagging. It's possible some queries on the data dumps could eliminate at least some of those possibilities.